# UINavigationController based app with FlipSideView with another UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, flipside

I'm trying to develop an app (game) with this architecture:

- Main view is a naviagtioncontroller based with navbar hidden
- in Main view I need a light info
  button to show a options/credits
  flipsideview
- this flipsideview must have another
  navigationcotroller with a right bar
  button to a "Done" system button

The problem is that the flipsideview doesn't show the done button and it seems to show the Main navigation controller...

This is the code.

AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

Main View (loaded from a XIB). Extract only of showInfo:

```
-(IBAction) showInfo:(id)sender {

    FlipSideViewController *controller = [[FlipSideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipSideView" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.title = @"Info";

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
                                                                                target:controller action:@selector(done:)];

    navController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
    controller.navController = navController;    
    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

    [doneButton release];
    [controller release];
    [navController release];

}



- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipSideViewController *)controller {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

FlipSideView. In the XIB I've only a blank view with outlet linked to the UIViewController view.

```
@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate;

@interface FlipSideViewController : UIViewController {

    id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

    UINavigationController *navController;

}


@property (nonatomic,assign) id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UINavigationController *navController;

-(IBAction)done;

@end

@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipSideViewController *)controller;
@end

}
```

Implementation file...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navController.navigationItem.title = @"Pippo";
}


    #pragma mark - User Methods

    - (IBAction)done {

        [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];

    }
```

The result is:

- Main View showing without navigation
  bar
- Click on info button
- Flipsideview showing with animation
  and navigation bar with title "Info" and not "pippo
  and not "Done" button on the right...

Where am I wrong??

Comment: Ok, i resolved moving the creation and assigning "Done" button into the viewDidLoad of FlipSide and, there, using self.navigationItem.XXX and self.navigationBar.XXX instead of self.navController.XXX.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you get two navigationBar with navigationItems on FlipsideViewController? I am fighting with this bug now.

Comment: Weel, it seems no. The only strange behaviour is that the first navigation bar is visible during the transation between flipside and main view... even if I se in viewWillAppear and viewDidDisappear the navigationBarHidden to true. After the transition the main navigation bar is no more visible, lik I want.